# TableView contents leads to heavy scroll and increase live bytes

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am pulling data from service in pagination and trying to display on table view.

Some of the contents/rows are in different languages, they leads to heavy scrolling and also increases the live bytes.

is there a way to handle this issue?

Live bytes are increasing but there are no leaks.

Regards,

Reno Jones

Comment: UItableview reuses cells, however a lot can be optimised for smoother  scrolling.

Comment: Has using different languages anything to do with your problem? If so, how?

Comment: Are you parsing the strings of the different languages or something like that?

Comment: @Spire - Yes, I have strings of different languages and I am already using the reusable cells. Thanks guys for the help.

Comment: Sounds like, If I comment out my Label on which I am setting the different languages text appears to work well for me.

Comment: @RenoJones probably the string parsing gets your memory and the table scrolling is slow. Try to parse them and put them into a dictionary or array and show them only from that dic/array (that's before populating the table)

Comment: I somewhat Figured it out, I was using the UILabel to display different languages which apparently was causing this, when I used UITextView instead, it saved much more than UILabel.